# Can't cast varchar(255) to float

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to either alter a column type to float or create a new one and copy the contents of the old, but in either case I get:

```
invalid input syntax for type numeric: "10:59"
```

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE videos ALTER COLUMN length TYPE numeric(10,2) USING CAST(length AS numeric(10,2));
```

I also tried just selecting the value as a float

```
select length::numeric(10,2) from videos;
```

but I get the same error.  Here is the column description

[image]

additionally i when I do

```
select '10.59'::numeric(10,2), length from videos;
```

it returns

```
numeric length
10.59   10:59
```

Comment: Clearly i need to pay more attention as obviously 10:59 is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have values that are not valid. `"10:59"` cannot be casted to fload.

```
SELECT '10:59'::float
-- ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "10:59"
```

Please note that your string value contains semicolon: `10:59` != `10.59`.

You need to update that value before altering table.

Comment: Update it to what? its just a string representation of clock time

Comment: @jwilcox09 Literal 10:59 is invalid numeric/float. You cannot change data type directly.